# Style.css not showing any effect after changing

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a problem with my style.css in wordpress.

When I trying to change anything like page background color or font style by editing the style.css then it doesn't reflect ant effect to my webpage.

Please help me

Comment: Make sure you are uploading and overwriting the existing style.css (inside of the correct directory) and clear any site/browser caches.